# Powershell: Paste Last Command

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Is there a way that I can get powershell to paste my last command into my current command line ?

For example, let's say that I type:

```
get-service
```

and decide that I want more information on it, so I would type:

```
get-help get-service
```

Instead it seems that there should be a shortcut so I could something like:

```
get-help %x
```

and get the same results as the shortcut **%x** in this example would be replaced with the previous command **get-service**. Maybe even a button on the keyboard to get the same result.  Of course this is a contrived example, but it seems that it would be really useful in more complex scenarios.  Is there anything like that available ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The automatic variable `$$` holds the most recent command.

So you can do

```
get-service
get-help $$
```

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell you have an variable for the last command "called" `$$` . Ex:

```
PS > $$
get-help

PS > Get-Service

Status  Name                               DisplayName                                           
------  ----                               -----------                                           
Running AdobeARMservice                    Adobe Acrobat Update Service                          

PS > get-help $$ -full

NAME
    Get-Service

PS > $$
-full

PS > Get-Help Get-Service

NAME
    Get-Service

PS > $$
Get-Service
```

However, as you can see in the example above, it stores the last part of the previous command, which may sometimes backfire at you.

Answer (score 1):

Up-arrow navigates back through your history, and you can edit previously-entered commands to execute them as new.

```
Get-Service
```

`Up-arrow`
`Home`

```
Help (space)
```